# TPL Dataflows with NServiceBus like lifetime

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, message-queue, nservicebus, tpl-dataflow

Just worked through a quick sandbox version of [what I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654371/multi-threaded-architecture-for-a-feeder-application).

The original requirements still stand - and this worked nicely in my console sandbox verison:

- Read a file (of account IDs), CSV format
- Download the account data
  file from the web for each account (by Id) (REST API)
- Pass the file to a converter that will produce a report (financial predictions etc)
  [~20ms]
- If the prediction threshold is within limits, run a parser to analyse the data [400ms]
- Generate a report for the analysis above [80ms]
- Upload all files generated to the web (REST API)

I'm trying to make use of NServiceBus this time as suggested but I'm finding it hard to workout how to make things fit.

I'm pushing a bulk of 20 account Ids into a message, that's read by NServiceBus Handler and they get Posted it to the BufferBlock one at a time. The reason for bulk loading is our systems use a very slow web-service to get account info - especially archived accounts (deceased etc) that take 3-4s sometimes! (don't worry about that for the moment)

How do I keep popping stuff into the BufferBlock and still have my TPL Dataflow active as I read messages etc? Do I configure the TPL Dataflow separately and wait for ever and just Post when a new batch of messages come through?

There are roughly 2 million accounts to process. Ideally I'd like the Account Report Generator (TPL-DF) to be alive all the time and I just push messages to its buffer which it will work through. It's the lifetime that confuses me.

Comment: I can't understand you question. The dataflow you build will run as long as you keep adding items to it. If you stop, it will stop. If you start again, it will start again too...

Comment: Ah my apologies, I meant how do I keep the consumer alive whilst the producer may stop sending stuff onto the queue for a little while? To avoid having to wire up the consumer all the time.

Comment: It depends on your specific code, but the consumer doesn't die. It just waits (synchronous or asynchronously). The moment you push more items to the dataflow it will resume processing.